# angular cli update CRASH

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, angular-cli

He actualizado de la versión 1.3 de angular cli a la 1.6.X y al hacer npm install me sale un error constante de webpack-subresource-integrity con webpack, actualicé webpack a la versión 3.X (lo instalé global y local) y sigue saliendo el mismo error. Les dejo imagen del log y también de mi package.json, espero puedan ayudarme!

Gracias de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: webpack esta desinstalado

Comment: @x-rw No se si eso sea amigo, ya que instalé webpack tanto global como localmente con npm install --global webpack y npm install --save-dev webpack respecetivamente.